# How do I replace a flange installed with primer?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

I had a leaky toilet and had to replace the subflooring in the bathroom. The flange is also rusty and a little warped and must be replaced. I've seen plenty of videos telling me to score the flange fitting and use a screwdriver or chisel to break the glue and remove the fitting from the pipe. However it looks like primer was used in my case and I can't get the fitting to budge. I'm afraid of breaking the pipe and ending up with a real mess.

What is the best way to remove the flange if it was installed using primer and glue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where the flange is broken you could look into a .[flange repair kit](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/catalog/servlet/Search?keyword=toilet%20flange%20repair&selectedCatgry=SEARCH%20ALL&langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053&Ns=None&Ntpr=1&Ntpc=1)
If that won't do it, I would cut the old flange at the pipe with a mandrel saw from the inside of the 3-4" pipe. Then get a flange with a longer neck that will glue onto the existing pipe. Try to cut the pipe as straight as posible.

Comment: Thanks! Will this make it impossible to glue the new flange in place? I suppose as long as the cut is really straight I should be ok...

Comment: Just finished this up. My flange is a little loose, but I'm sure I'll figure something out there.

Comment: You used the PVC glue? And screwed the flange into the sub floor? Should be secure if you did that.